# mongoosastic [mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [string] declared on field [type]

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

Here is the error

```
{ Error: [mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [string] declared on field [type]
    at respond (/home/jilu/Documents/project/backup/assignment_ok/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:289:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/home/jilu/Documents/project/backup/assignment_ok/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:248:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/jilu/Documents/project/backup/assignment_ok/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:164:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/home/jilu/Documents/project/backup/assignment_ok/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4968:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  status: 400,
  displayName: 'BadRequest',
  message: '[mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [string] declared on field [type]',
```

and mapping is not creating

Please explain an configuration of mongoosastic.

I am using express JS and MongoDb as back end.

After if call search Api I am getting:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Hits array is null and total is zero and mapping also showing empty.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue after setting up Mongoosastic 4.3 + Elasticsearch 6.2 and the issue is due to incompatibility of Mongoosastic with Elasticsearch 6.x!!

If you google, you'll find that Elasticsearch changed the default type from  'string' to 'text' and its documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings). At the end of the post they say the following:

> That said, you should still look into upgrading them since we plan on removing this backward compatibility layer when we release Elasticsearch 6.0.

And there are more incompatibilities I found on Mongoosastic with latest Elasticsearch 6.2.  I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/pull/420) to make these changes but not sure when/if it will get accepted. Until they fix the official version, I am using my clone of [Mongoosastic](https://github.com/avadhpatel/mongoosastic) with the fix until they patch the official repo.